# Not able to get the values in one row in HTML table through ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Following is a simple code which I wrote casually for fetching the values in a table through ng-repeat, however, ng-repeat is filling in the values in different rows. for eg: 1st element: 1st row; second element: second row.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="D:\hTML\library\angular.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src=D:\hTML\jsemployee.js></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller= "ctrl">
<h1> Table is Table</h1>


<table border="1">
    <thead>
  <thead>

        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
          <tbody ng-repeat="employee in employees| filter:searchText:exactmatch">
        <tr >
          <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
          <td>{{employee.gender}}</td>
          <td>{{employee.city}}</td>
          <td>{{employee.country}}</td>
</table>
</body>
```

AngularJS:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){

  $scope.employees=[{name: "Gerald"},{gender:"male"}, {city:"Colorado"}, {country:"USA"}]
})
```

Output:

[image]

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: The image link you are using is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your employees array, you are having each field as a object.Instead, it should be like this,

```
  $scope.employees=[{name: "Gerald",gender:"male", city:"Colorado", country:"USA"}];
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.employees=[{name: "Gerald",gender:"male", city:"Colorado", country:"USA"}];
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Hello AngularJS</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ctrl">     
 <table border="1">
 <thead>
    <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody >
    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees| filter:searchText:exactmatch">
          <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
          <td>{{employee.gender}}</td>
          <td>{{employee.city}}</td>
          <td>{{employee.country}}</td>
     </tr>
</table>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks All. I did not check it. Thanks for mentioning it out.

Answer (score 2):

Please use Below code

```
  $scope.employees=[{name: "Gerald",gender:"male",city:"Colorado",country:"USA"}]
```

You are defined a variable of having values with different indexes so while using **ng-repeat** , it is taking values with different indexes.that's why you are not getting in single row.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create single element in an array so that it will iterate only once and create a row only once instead of repeat 4 times.

Try this :

```
$scope.employees=[{"name":"Gerald", "gender":"male", "city":"Colorado", "country":"USA"}];
```

instead of

```
$scope.employees=[{name: "Gerald"},{gender:"male"}, {city:"Colorado"}, {country:"USA"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

change your json format and check as below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody ng-repeat="employee in employees| filter:searchText:exactmatch">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.gender}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.city}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.country}}</td>
        </table>

    </div>
    <script>
        angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {

            $scope.employees = [{ name: "Gerald", gender: "male", city: "Colorado", country: "USA" }]
        })
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```